# Looping with in an array to get required data in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I have an JSON as mentioned below:

```
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "Name": "x",
  "Email": "z@epsilon.com ",
  "Designation": "Manager",
  "Project": "x",
  "Skills": [{
      "Technology": "Big Data- Hadoop, Hive, HDFS",
      "Level": "Theoretical",
      "TotalExperience": ""
    },
    {
      "Technology": "Oracle PL/SQL",
      "Level": "Intermediate",
      "TotalExperience": ""
    },
    {
      "Technology": "Informatica PowerExchange 8.x",
      "Level": "Intermediate",
      "TotalExperience": ""
    },
    {
      "Technology": "IBM Datastage 7.5",
      "Level": "Beginer",
      "TotalExperience": ""
    },
    {
      "Technology": "MS Word",
      "Level": "Expert",
      "TotalExperience": ""
    },
    {
      "Technology": "USnit testing",
      "Level": "Expert",
      "TotalExperience": ""
    }
  ]
}];
```

I want to show it as a tabular format in angular as `Name`, `Project`, `Designation`, `Skills` (Under `skills`: `theoretical`, `expert`, `intermediate`)  and then the data.

I am able to achieve all but only skills which is an inner table am not able loop though correctly

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and we can point out how to fix it

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how it needs to look and how it's looking as of now with your current implementation in place? Also, please add your implementation as far.

Comment: share your angular typescript and service code.

Comment: i am doing *ngFor="let employee of employees ; let rowIndex = index in the table body which is the parent one and the below code is for skils column whcih is again a table                        
<tbody> <tr *ngFor="let skill of employee.Skills; let i=index">
 <td *ngIf="skill.Level=='Theoretical'"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{skill.Technology}}</a></td></tr></tbody>

Comment: i am getting employees object as of now and showing in the UI so trying to extract from employees object only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this:

Template:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Project</td>
    <td>Designation</td>
    <td>Skills</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let datum of data">
      <td>{{ datum.Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.Project }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.Designation }}</td>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <td>Theoritical</td>
          <td>Beginer</td>
          <td>Intermediate</td>
          <td>Expert</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ filterSkillBy(datum.Skills, 'Theoretical') }}</td>
            <td>{{ filterSkillBy(datum.Skills, 'Beginer') }}</td>
            <td>{{ filterSkillBy(datum.Skills, 'Intermediate') }}</td>
            <td>{{ filterSkillBy(datum.Skills, 'Expert') }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  data = [...];

  filterSkillBy(skills: any[], by) {
    return skills.filter(skill => skill.Level === by).map(skill => skill.Technology).toString();
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-complex-table-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: it worked properly but  i wanted to apply link on all skills which on click of particular skills this should will filter but in this scenario it's clicking on the skills it will  click the whole td elements so filters wont work.Any solution for this please guide.